# Delphi Insertion Sort on ListBox Runtime Error.

Tags: delphi

I have created a simple form which allows end user to add names. The program worked fine when i used integers (i.e. asked end user for an integer, it was add to list, and then all integers in listbox were sorted). I'm now trying to get Strings to work (i.e. ask for a name, adds it to list box, and upon clicking sort, it runs an insertion sort).  It compiles ok, however, i'm always getting a runtime error "Access Violation at [long Hexadecimal number] in module KernelBase.dll".    Errggh!

```
  unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    btnAdd: TButton;
    txtEdit: TEdit;
    ListBox: TListBox;
    btnSort: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSortClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure InsertionSort(var list: array of string;first,last:integer);
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;
  List: array [1..10] of string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure tform4.insertionSort(var list: array of string; first,last:integer);
var CurrentIndex, Index,count:integer; CurrentValue: string;
begin
    CurrentIndex:=first+1;
    while CurrentIndex <= last do
    begin
       currentValue:=list[CurrentIndex];
       Index:=CurrentIndex-1;
       While (list[index] > currentValue) and (index >= 0)
       do
        begin
            list[Index+1]:= list[Index];
            Index:=Index-1;
        end;
        list[index+1]:=currentValue;
        CurrentIndex:=CurrentIndex+1;
    end;
    listbox.Clear;
    for count := 1 to length(list) do
          listbox.Items.Add((list[count]));
end;

procedure TForm4.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
listbox.Items.Add(txtEdit.Text);
txtEdit.Text:='';
end;

procedure TForm4.btnSortClick(Sender: TObject);
var last:integer;
begin
 last:=length(list);
 showmessage(inttostr(last));
 insertionSort(list, 1, last);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var step:integer;
begin
for step := 1 to length(list) do
  listbox.Items.Add((list[step]));
end;

 begin
    list[1]:='Zulu';
    list[2]:='Yankee';
    list[3]:='XRay';
    list[4]:='Whiskey';
    list[5]:='Victor';
    list[6]:='Uniform';
    list[7]:='Tango';
    list[8]:='Sierra';
    list[9]:='Romeo';
    list[10]:='Quebec';
end.
```

Comment: The `InsertionSort` is operating on an `array of string`. This means that the list index is starting from zero. You are passing first,stop based on 1.

Comment: A big problem seems to be confusion over index basing. Your code has a mix of 1 based and 0 based indices. Don't do that. Use 0 based everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see your point, as i believe i have stuck to the 1-base throughout apart from following line  in Insertion Sort procedure:         _While (list[index] > currentValue) and (index >= 0)_  which i believe is actual part of insertion sort algorithm.

Comment: No. Open arrays are zero based. You've picked the wrong convention. Pick zero based. Then your code will fit in with open arrays and dynamic arrays.

Comment: I'd also advise you to put your sorting code outside of your GUI forms, in due course. This is low-level foundational code and should not be tied to your GUI. Done well you can have concise sorting algos that are able to sort any type of data.

Comment: Like, as a type of Unit Class? I see your point - this 'sorting' algorithm could be called by any form.   Still, gaining runtime errors here...will keep trying.

Comment: Just declare list as `array[0..9] of string` or declare a specific type.

Comment: @ LU RD.  Yes, i did that immediately. Then changed the arguments of the call to InsertionSort(0,last)...where for last i used Length(List)-1.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: `for count := 1 to length(list) do` is wrong too.

Comment: Then there's also the logical error that you add the new name to the ListBox, but you sort the List array and add the array items back to the list after clearing it. Thus the new name gets lost.

Comment: Good point Tom. To extend this open array, I guess i just have to re-declare my array at the beginning to [0..10]

Comment: @user then your array is too long, now it has 11 instead of 10 elements

Comment: As it is now declared it is a very fixed array (the array parameter of the sort procedure is an open array). Change the array declaration to `List: array of string;`. That will make it dynamic and you can change its length with `SetLength(List, NewLength);`Then also use `Low(List)` and `High(List)` in the sort procedure.

Comment: When should i use SetLength(list,last)? On the FormCreate event?

Comment: @user Whenever you are going to add items. Since you are adding items in FormCreate, that's a good place. Then also, consider adding the new name to the List array, and setting its length before.

Comment: On the FormCreate event, does the program know the value of high() considering 10 elements have been declared between the Begin and End. clause?  I'm wondering because I'm figuring out do i have to apply SetLength method inside the iteration  For step:= first to last ... listbox.items.add(list[step])?

Comment: @user In FormCreate you call `SetLength(List, 10);` because you are going to add the 10 test names right after. Then, in the for loop you copy the names to the ListBox. In the btnAddClick, you call `SetLength(List, Length(List)+1);`and add the name from the TEdit to the last position in the List array.

Comment: @user I just noticed that you have an old style initialization part in your file. Had already forgot about that possibility and thought it was just a copy paste error. You should not use the old style anymore. Use the new style with the word `initialization`. That enables you to also have a `finalization` section. Anyway, the length of the array must be set before you assign the names to the array. Do both in either `FormCreate`or `initialization`.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. When you have a new question, ask a new question. You are allowed to ask new questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Don't know why this was given a -2 rating though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious problem is that you mix one based and zero based array indexing. Open arrays are zero based. Your array is one based. You have not accounted for this difference.

Accounting for the difference is not the way forward though. Mixing conventions leads to mass confusion. Pick one convention and stick to it. Since the Delphi designers picked zero based already for open arrays and dynamic arrays the choice is clear. Use zero based arrays consistently.

Note that you don't actually need to pass the first and last array indices. You can find the first and last indices of an open array with `low()` and `high()`.

```
While (list[index] > currentValue) and (index >= 0)
```

This condition is the wrong way round. You need to test for `index` being positive before accessing the array.

```
While (index >= 0) and (list[index] > currentValue)
```

You really need to keep the sorting code separated from your GUI. That way you can re-use the sorting code.

The variable name `count` is a bad choice for a loop variable. We use that name to represent the number of items in a collection.

There may be more errors. You should be able to find them using the debugger.

Comment: Thanks David, tried that. Took out the parameters in the Procedure Declaration.  Still getting Runtime Error.

Comment: Are you using the debugger? This would be a great opportunity to learn some debugging skills.

Comment: That's it!  I don't understand how the order of the two conditions bear influence on this?  Surely, order doesn't matter...it simply means BOTH things must be true?

Comment: No, they are evaluated in order left to right, and short circuited. Think what happens when index is -1. Do you really want to evaluate `list[index]`. If the code seemed to work for integers then that was by chance. It was broken there too. You just see it now because undefined values are likely not to be valid strings.